# Terminal Command to install imported module of a module

Tags: python-3.x

Lets assume I have a module say utility.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from datetime import datetime
import os
import random
import sys
import threading

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
.....
```

I'd like to import this in my drive.py. I have it saved in my local directory and have in my first line

```
from . import utility
```

Is that possible, to issue a command in terminal to find the non-local modules ( tensorflow, numpy, etc), and install them using pip?

Any workaround would be appreciated.

CS

Comment: I think the solution for this will be to use requirements.py and in this, you can save all the modules installed by `pip freeze > requirements.py` and run `pip install -r requirements.py` to get it all installed in one command.

Comment: thank you for the hint. I will consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you'd like the command to parse the file's imports and install missing dependancies automatically, then no it is not possible.
There are modules that are not imported with the pip's package name. For example the package `facebook-sdk` is imported as `import facebook`, making impossible to deduct the package name from the import.